Why are raid modules always loaded?
This is driving me seriously crazy:
$ doas lsmod | fgrep raid | fgrep ' 0'
raid10                 73728  0
raid456               192512  0
raid1                  57344  0
raid0                  24576  0

even though:

none of my filesystems or swaps is on RAID
I don't use btrfs or such that may need RAID functionality implicitly
I see no udev rules or systemd units directly loading these

There are some udev rules related to lvm mentioning RAID in their comments ... but lvm is disabled in systemd

Perhaps they are being built into initrd via dracut. If they are loaded early, then that is what I would look at.

@Bib they are definitely in the early userspace image. This is an ubuntu derived system, so using initramfs-tools. I can see they are there with lsinitramfs. But that by itself doesn't explain why they're loaded. Maybe I have found the answer, though -- I also see that one of the boot scripts in the  initramfs runs mdadm, and I guess mdadm is capable of loading these modules unconditionally to do its job.
